# Nightwatchjs zooming out of browser

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js, nightwatch

To zoom out of a browser ctrl & - can be used to reduce the zoom levels. I want to incorporate this into my automated testing suite where I have used nightwatchjs. This is to allow all objects on webpage to seen.

I am trying to zoom out on the browser to have the browser zoom size set to 50%. Is there anyway in Nightwatch that this can be done?

I have tried to use

```
browser.keys([browser.Keys.CONTROL, "browser.Keys.SUBTRACT", browser.Keys.NULL])
```

However this does not seem to work. Has anyone tried to zoom browser pages out using Nightwatchjs if so how can this be done can this be done or know how to do this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, I have added more details to the description however it may seem vague as I am trying to see if anyone has ever came across a similar problem when using Nightwatchjs